# How to configure elasticserach 7.3 autocompletion for the following scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, autocomplete

I need help with prefix autocomplete suggestions from elasticsearch 7.3 documents with a multiple fields search and an associated field type in the output to categorize the suggested term type.

tried with search_as_you_type field type and adding multiple completion analyzers with no luck so far. I wanted a solution that is very easy to implement, eliminates duplicates and reduce my memory footprint. Something like a Redis sorted set.

Here is my el indexed docs and expected auto-complete results.

```
{
    "id": "7cBLdyLTkPNTC8c1Ntq",
    "tech": {
        "body": "Nikon D600",
        "gear": "Nikon AF-S Nikkor 16-35mm f/4 ED VR"
    },
    "artist": {
        "name": " Hilton Paris"
    },
    "details": {
        "place": "Nepal",
        "text": "Mount Everest .Natures mirror",
        "tags": [
            "mountain",
            "rock",
            "nature",
            "wooden trail",
            "mirror",
            "past and furious"
        ],
        "score": 0.87
    },
    "createdDate": {
        "_seconds": 1566260863,
        "_nanoseconds": 12000000
    }
 }

 {
    "id": "8cBLdyLTkPNTC8c1Ntq",
    "tech": {
        "body": "Panasonic Lumix DC-S1R Mirrorless",
        "gear": "Panasonic Lumix S PRO 50mm"
    },
    "artist" : {
        "name": "Jhon Gabriel"
          },
    "details": {
        "place": "paris",
        "text": "mirror lake reflection",
        "tags": [
            "lake",
            "rock",
            "nature",
            "water"
        ],
        "score": 0.87
    },
    "createdDate": {
        "_seconds": 1566260863,
        "_nanoseconds": 12000000
    },
 }
```

search for "pa" should give the following output.

```
 output [ {
    "type" :"artist",
   "value" : "Paris Peace",

},
{
    "type" :"body",
    "value" : "Panasonic",

},
{
     "type" :"gear",
     "value" : " Panasonic Lumix S PRO 50mm"
},
{
    "type" :"place",
     "value" : "paris"
},
{
"type" : "tag",
"value" : "past and furious"
}

]
```

What i need is

for a given input prefix e.g 'pa', get all the matching terms from the elsticsearch datastore with the following conditions.

input satisfies a case insensitive prefix to one of the following fields

  1.1  "tech.body"  ---> token level prefix matching, output only the token value

  1.2  "tech.gear"  ---> token level prefix matching, output full string value of the filed.
    
   e.g if tehc.gear has a token with 'pa' as the prefix, 
     
  output should be the full value of this field ,like "Panasonic Lumix S PRO 50mm"
 
 1.3 "artist.name" --> token level prefix matching
  
 1.4  "details.place" --> token level prefix matching

  1.5  "details.tags" --> token level prefix matching, output full string value of the filed, eg. pa--> "past and furious"

  1.6  "details.text" --> token level prefix matching

Any help here is highly appreciated, as this is turning out to be a blocker for an upcoming release.